# How to visualize (make plot) of regression output against categorical input variable?

Tags: machine-learning, visualization, categorical-data, linear-regression

I am doing linear regression with multiple variables. In my data I have **n = 143** features and **m = 13000** training examples. Some of my features are continuous (ordinal) variables (area, year, number of rooms). But I also have categorical variables (district, color, type). For now I visualized some of my feautures against predicted price. For example here is the plot of `area` against predicted `price`:
[image]

Since `area` is continuous ordinal variable I had no troubles visualizing the data. But now I wanted to somehow visualize dependency of my categorical variables (such as district) on predicted price.
For categorical variables I used one-hot (dummy) encoding. 

For example that kind of data:
[image]

turned to this format:
[image]

If I were using ordinal encoding for districts this way:

```
DistrictA - 1
DistrictB - 2
DistrictC - 3
DistrictD - 4
DistrictE - 5
```

I would plot this values against predicted price pretty easy by putting 1-5 to X axis and price to Y axis.

But I used dummy coding and now I do not know how can I show (visualize) dependency between price and categorical variable 'District' represented as series of zeros and ones.

How can I make a plot showing a regression line of districts against predicted price in case of using dummy coding?

Comment: Cross-posted on Stats.SE, SO, and DataScience.SE: http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/186027/2921, http://stackoverflow.com/q/34193685/781723, http://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9301/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34193685/how-to-visualize-make-plot-of-regression-output-against-categorical-input-vari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible first step is to convert the data back to the original coding.
This is called in SQL *unpivot*, in R *melt*.

Here an R example

```
> my.df <- read.table(
+ text = "DistrictA     DistrictB    DistrictC    DistrictD     DistrictE     Price
+         1             0            0            0             0             10000
+         0             1            0            0             0             20000
+         0             0            1            0             0             30000
+         0             0            0            1             0             40000
+         0             0            0            0             1             50000"
+      , header = TRUE)
> my.df
  DistrictA DistrictB DistrictC DistrictD DistrictE Price
1         1         0         0         0         0 10000
2         0         1         0         0         0 20000
3         0         0         1         0         0 30000
4         0         0         0         1         0 40000
5         0         0         0         0         1 50000

> library(reshape)
> subset(melt(my.df, id="Price", variable = "District"),value == 1)[,c(1,2)]
   Price  District
1  10000 DistrictA
7  20000 DistrictB
13 30000 DistrictC
19 40000 DistrictD
25 50000 DistrictE
```

After that you plot the Price dependent on a factor variable. You may additionally consider to order the factor based on the predicted price.

I provide no details, as you don't tagged your tool, but I would recommend additional to a scatter plot to consider a box plot and/or density plot - always combined with the prediction value from the model for each factor level.